# Lua Input Problem

Tags: input, lua

I'm new to the Lua I/O, but have been using Lua elsewhere for almost two years now. I have this line:

```
for line in io.lines("myfile.txt") do
```

but it always results in a "No such file or directory" error. "myfile.txt" is in the same directory as the Lua file.

Where should I put the file "myfile.txt"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`for line in io.lines(assert(io.open("myfile.txt"))) do`

-- The lines function accepts a file in its argument, while on the other hand, open accepts a string and returns the file.

Comment: Wait, now it gives me "Bad argument #1 - string expected, got userdata."

Comment: Nevermind - I used io.lines() and set the default input before with io.input("myfile.txt").

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem but fixed it with the following code - This code demonstrates iteration with io.open ...

```
function getHostnameFromHostFile(ip)
    local hostName = "unknown";
    local hostFile = io.open("/etc/hosts");

    for line in hostFile:lines() do
        if line and string.find(line, ip) then
            hostName = line:match("[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]+");
        end
    end
    return hostName;
end
```